# writing multiple try and except in python

Tags: python, try-catch

I want to know what is the most elegant way of writing `try`..`except` statements in python. Assume I have this code:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            do_1(line)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            do_2(line)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            do_3(line)
        except:
            pass
        ...
        ...
```

What is the best way of writing this? My actions are sequential. However, if `do_1` fails I still want to perform `do_2`. If all of them are in one `try`..`except` block, then if `do_1` fails, I will never reach `do_2`. Is this the right way, or can I have one `except` for all of `d0_i` actions?

Comment: You don't say anything about what's inside the do_X functions, so I'm going out on a limb here, but I have a feeling that maybe exceptions are not right in the first place. The pattern seems to be that you're trying several operations on each line (some kind of pattern matching?) and if there's an exception it's just swallowed anyway. Maybe use of return values could be a good choice? Exceptions are slow, so to write code where multiple exceptions are expected in a tight loop would result in slow code.  Of course I don't know the details of the code, so I might be wrong for your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would factor out the common code which is your `try/except` statements. Something like:

```
def run_safely(f, *args):
    try:
        f(*args)
    except SpecificException:
        # handle appropriately here
        pass

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
   for line in f:
       run_safely(do_1, line)
       run_safely(do_2, line)
       run_safely(do_3, line)
```

Comment: One nitpick: The exception handling causes `run_safely` to need to operate at more than one level of abstraction at a tim. I.e, the caller of `run_safely` probably knows more about how to handle the exception than `run_safely` itself; but the exception is --- of necessity --- hidden from the caller.

Answer (score 9):

It's simple enough to write this as a loop:

```
for action in [do_1, do_2, do_3, ...]:
    try:
        action(line)
    except AppropriateExceptionType:
        pass
```

Comment: @Nick You could create an anonymous function on the fly if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need each `do_<Step>` function to run inside the `finally` block of the previous one, like so:

```
try:
    do_1(line)
    except:
        # Handle failure
        pass
    finally:
        # Run regardless
        try:
            do_2(line)
        except:
            # Handle failure
        finally:
            # Run regardless
            try:
                do_3(line)
                ...
```

This chains the functions together through the `finally` block. Notice that in the event of an exception at any step, the exception is handled before starting the next step, which is guaranteed to run regardless of whether an exception is generated or not.

---

Since your functions all have the same shape (taking the same number and type of arguments), you can abstract out this pattern into a function, like `tryChain` below:

```
def tryChain(functions, *sharedArgs)
    f = functions.pop()
    try:
        f(*sharedArgs)
    finally:
        tryChain(functions)

try:
    tryChain([do_1, do_2, ...], line, arg2, ...)
except SpecificException:
    # Handle exception here, which may be propagated from any of the actions
    pass
```

Note that in this case, only the last exception is thrown back to the caller; the others are hidden. (You could handle the exceptions inside `tryChain` as well, with an `except` block inserted there; or, you could pass in an error handler for each step; or a map from exception types to the appropriate handler, and re-throw the error if none of them matches  — but at that point, you're practically reinventing exception handling.)